# Oracle and HTTP - Any way to globally set the time out for HTTP connections

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way not doing this

```
Utl_http.set_transfer_timeout(...);
```

but set it globally for the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_HTTP.html#GUID-D4063487-6F69-4757-B77A-AF2B93E5DAFE), "The default value of the time out is 60 seconds" so no I don't think you can change the global default.